# How to get only sub directory name in certain directory

Tags: readdir

I made to get sub directories using readdir.
But it takes so long time if there is a directory with over 670 k files and 2 sub directories.

How can I get only sub directory in short time?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
    find . -type d
```

this finds only directories and not files